# Extract XML-TEI attributes from a file

Tags: python, xml, tei

Good morning, I am working on a code to extract data from an XML-TEI marked-up file of a poem and I would like to print the list of the 'pos' attributes for each one of the lines of the poem ('l'). ('w' is the name of the word tag contained within the 'l' tag)

```
<l n="1"> <w pos="PREP" msd="--" lemma="de">De</w> <w pos="REL" msd="--" lemma="qui">qua</w> <w pos="ADV" msd="--" lemma="saepe">saepe</w> <w pos="PRON" msd="--" lemma="tu">tibi</w> <w pos="PUN" msd="--" lemma=",">,</w> </l> <l n="2"> <w pos="ADV" msd="--" lemma="non">non</w> <w pos="V" msd="IND" lemma="licet_est">licet</w> </l> <l n="3"> <w pos="PREP" msd="--" lemma="de">de</w> <w pos="REL" msd="--" lemma="qui">qua</w> <w pos="ADV" msd="--" lemma="saepe">saepe</w> </l>
```

```
result_4=bs_content.find_all('l')
for x in result_4:
  print(len(x.find_all('w')))
  for x in x.find_all('w'):
    a=x.get('pos')
    print(a)
```

The result is currently the following:

5

PREP

REL

ADV

PRON

PUN

2

ADV

V

3

PREP

REL

ADV

But I would like to have

5

['PREP', 'REL', 'ADV', 'PRON', 'PUN']

2

['ADV', 'V']

3

['PREP', 'REL', 'ADV']

May anyone help me? Thanks

Comment: Upload *XML-TEI marked-up file* and explain what is the data you are looking for.

Comment: Update the post with this data - not as a comment. Add the expected output as well. As **TEXT** - not images. Make sure that the XML you post is **VALID**